# Longest common substring

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to create a program which will receive two strings and compeer between, and returns the largest common letters in the order they appear.

examples:

```
string1="a" string2="b"
return ""

string1="abc" string2="ac"
return "ac"

string1:“abcd” string2:“ acdbb”
return:“ abcd"
```

I need to write 3 codes - "normal way", recursive way and "in memorization" way.

So far I've succeed to code:

```
def l_c_s(s1, s2):
for i in range(1 + len(s1))]:
mi = [[0] * (1 + len(s2))
long, x_long = 0, 0
for x in range(1, 1 + len(s1)):
    for y in range(1, 1 + len(s2)):
        if s1[x - 1] == s2[y - 1]:
            m[x][y] = m[x - 1][y - 1] + 1
            if m[x][y] > long:
                long = m[x][y]
                x_long = x
        m[x][y] = 0
return s1[x_long - long: x_long]
```

But I don't get what I wanted. just run this code for the `string1="abc" string2="ac"`
and the see what happens.

Moreover, I have no idea how to make it recursive and neither to write it in memo.

Comment: This looks more like a common subset since the order does not matter.

Comment: `abcd` is not a substring of `acdbb`

Comment: Hence the question: do you want the result of `"abcdd"` and `"add"` be `"ad"` or `"add"`?

Comment: returns the largest common letters in the order they appear... therefore - add

Comment: How about `"abcd"` and `"cdab"`? Should be `"abcd"`?

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is really longest common sub-sequence, here is a version using memoization:

```
s1 = 'abcdd'
s2 = 'add'
mem = [[-1] * len(s2)] * len(s1)
matched = []

def lcs(i,j):
    if i < 0 or j < 0:
        return 0
    if mem[i][j] >= 0:
        return mem[i][j]
    if s1[i] == s2[j]:
        p = 1 + lcs(i-1, j-1)
        if p > mem[i][j]:
            mem[i][j] = p
            matched.append(s1[i])
    return max(mem[i][j], lcs(i-1, j), lcs(i, j-1))

lcs_length = lcs(len(s1)-1, len(s2)-1)
lcs = "".join(matched)

print 'LCS: <%s> of length %d' %  (lcs, lcs_length)
```

Comment: First of all, thank you very much sir. Can you add and tell me what is the "normal" recursive way, without the memoization thing? Thanks again.

Comment: Memoization is the technique of caching the results for each sub-state of the problem, so that they can be retrieved instantly when queried again without the need to re-compute (i.e. no need roll out the recursion from top again). It is built on top of the "normal" recursive way that you mentioned. Thus, if you do not want to memoize, simply remove all mem[i][j] checks and updates. In that case, the reconstruction of the actual lcs string will need to be modified appropriately as well.